# Changing query variable, then executing it again

Tags: php, mysql, session, dreamweaver

I am working on a PHP page that shows a table with query results. I want 2 buttons, with 'next' and 'previous', which change a variable used in this query:

```
SELECT les.lesuur, les.clustercode, les.lokaal, les.leraar, les.status 
FROM les, zitin 
WHERE zitin.leerlingnummer='$dimGebruiker' 
    AND zitin.clustercode=les.clustercode 
    AND les.dag='$huidigedag' 
ORDER BY les.lesuur
```

$huidigedag is the one that should be changed. This is what I have in the beginning of the PHP code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["huidigedag"])){
    $_SESSION["huidigedag"] = 1;
}
$huidigedag = $_SESSION["huidigedag"];
```

Then, I added a link to the two buttons (arrow images):

```
<a href="volgende.php">
```

(volgende means next)

This is volgende.php:

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION["huidigedag"] = $_SESSION["huidigedag"] + 1;
    header("location:leerlingrooster.php");
?>
```

However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I echo'd $huidigedag, and noticed it stayed on 1, without changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `session_start()` to the beginning of `volgende.php`

Comment: Doesnt change anything :( EDIT: It did :D In the speed, I forgot to sync the files, now it works :) Thanks! How such small things can change my mood haha

Answer (score 0):

I would change volgende.php to:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["huidigedag"] = (!isset($_SESSION["huidigedag"])) ? 1 : ($_SESSION["huidigedag"] + 1);
   header("location:leerlingrooster.php");
   exit;
?>
```